# Android: unable to click the bottom TextView after translate animation within a FrameLayout

Tags: android, animation, textview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout in which I have placed two identical TextViews.
I want to be able to translate the first view to the left (which I have done and is working like a charm). However I want to be able to click the TextView underneath it to perform an action.

When I try to click the bottom TextView, the top TextView gets clicked again instead. I have a feeling this is because the way animations are rendered and the change in actual x,y position doesn't take effect.

This is what I have so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:id="@+id/unbutt"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:text="@string/hello" 
        android:id="@+id/butt" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity implements AnimationListener, OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private class BottomViewClick implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Second Click", 5).show();
    }

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.butt); 
    tv.setBackgroundColor(0xffb71700);
    tv.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.unbutt); 
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(0xffb700ff);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(new BottomViewClick());

}

    private boolean revealed = false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation a ;
        if(!revealed)
            a = new TranslateAnimation(0f, -200f, 0f, 0f);
        else
            a = new TranslateAnimation(-200f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
        a.setDuration(500);
        a.setFillAfter(true);
        a.setAnimationListener(this);
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        if(revealed)
            revealed = false;
        else
            revealed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have ICS in the tag, so I assume that's what your target is.  In that case, the `Animation` objects you're using are essentially deprecated in favor of the [Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) class.  The old way of doing it only moves the visual location of the `View` while the physical location remains the same.  You would have to move it yourself by manipulating the margins of the view.  Using an `ObjectAnimator` on the other hand allows you to physically move the object along with it's visual component.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html